Errors in expo after switching to React Native New Architecture
After i enabled the new arc in my expo react native project by adding
{
  "expo": {
    "newArchEnabled": true
  }
}

to my app.json file, i start randomly having crashes sourcing from different parts of the app and when i search the web there is no entries related to these issues and i am starting to think that it is just me. Please if you see these issues too let me know.
Here are the errors:
This one just happens when i use a modal
Foundation] *** Assertion failure in -[RCTViewComponentView unmountChildComponentView:index:](), /Users/p/Desktop/expo-app/node_modules/react-native/React/Fabric/Mounting/ComponentViews/View/RCTViewComponentView.mm:162
[CoreFoundation] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempt to unmount a view which has a different index. (parent: <RNCSafeAreaProviderComponentView: 0x351b622f0; frame =
(0 0; 402 874); tag = 10; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000348f5e0>>, child: <RCTViewComponentView: 0x358244670; frame = (0 0; 402 874); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 3230; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000340b8e0>>, index: 4, actual index: 3, tag
at index: 3232)'


This one happens even if the app is standing still without any actions on the main page.
[CoreGraphics] Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.
[CoreGraphics] If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

This one happens when refreshing the app
[CoreFoundation] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to get
exported dimensions: AccessibilityManager is nil'

Seems like some fundamental incompatibility is going on.
I have checked all the expo and react native issues, these are pretty much non-existent.
I appreciate any help on this subject, i don't want to go back to the previous arch and reverse all the work i did for switching.
